# Neo4j - database shutdown

Tags: scala, neo4j, shutdown-hook

I am using Neo4j embedded in my Scala project. I have been including

```
ShutdownHookThread {
    shutdown(ds)
    }
```

the above piece of code in each and every function before the beginning of transaction. Do I need to include it in every function. What happens if I don't include it?

Answer (score 2):

`ShutdownHookThread` registers a piece of code to be executed when your application is about to exit. You need to use it only once - somewhere in your app bootstrap code, cause there is no sense to shutdown the database more than one time.

Comment: Different functions are called for different user actions. So, once an action is performed by the user I need to shutdown the database right?

Comment: Usually the database is opened once on app startup and closed once on app shutdown. There is no sense to repeat that on every user action - slows it down and causes concurrency issues.

Comment: what do you mean by app startup and closing? Mine is a web application!

Comment: In context of java web applications those correspond to the methods `contextInitialized` and `contextDestroyed` of the `ServletContextListener`.